# Any way to flash a custom rom without twrp recovery?( It doesn't work on my device)

Tags: rooting, root-access, recovery-mode, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I am trying to root my Galaxy Note 10.1 (sm P605). I've already upgraded the firmware with odin and flashed twrp with odin as well. Now after flashing twrp it boots normally then I switched it off and tried entering recovery mode. It shows me **'Recovery is not Seandroid Enforcing**'. Now after getting this error multiple times I flashed the twrp again with auto reboot unchecked in odin. I keep getting the error again

I followed some steps on the XDA forum for this device and it said uncheck auto reboot but that I've already tried. I tried kingsroot but it just doesn't work as well.

Comment: [TWRP](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxynote1012014qcom.html) is working fine. start from scratch and read more careful. Be aware of [dm-verity](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3919714), [RMM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535) protection and [Vaultkeeper](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3918699) on newer devices (if that concerns your device). not seandroid enforcing mean your TWRP has successful switched kernel into selinux permissive mode (which is desired), nothing to worry about and unrelated to your issue

Comment: Then how to make it work? I've tried everything again from scratch but still stuck on Seandroid not enforcing.

Comment: you must boot straight into recovery after flashing. try another build https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3635803

Comment: Thank you so much this one worked